# MATLAB Perceptron from scratch - OR function

Tags: matlab, neural-network, training-data, perceptron

my first time asking a question.

I'm teaching myself neural networks and am currently trying to program a perceptron algorithm. I want to train it for the OR function, but it isn't working. I have absolutely no idea regarding what I am doing wrong, and there are no solutions on the internet that don't use a toolbox.

```
input = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1]%input vector
num_in = 4;% number of iterations
desired_out = [0;1;1;1] %desired output
bias = -1; %bias
w=zeros(2,1); %weight vector, initially zero
iterations = 100; % number of iterations to go through

for i = 1:iterations
     out = zeros(4,1);
     for j = 1:num_in %go per row of x
          y = bias+input(j,1)*w(1,1)+input(j,2)*w(2,1) %sum
          if(out(j,1)~=desired_out(j,1))  % modify weights and bias if mismatch exists
             bias = bias+desired_out(j,1);
             w(1,1) =w(1,1)+input(j,1)*desired_out(j,1);
             w(2,1) = w(2,1)+input(j,2)*desired_out(j,1);
          end
     end
end
out %print the output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which perceptron algorithm you are following but I think [the one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Learning_algorithm) is what you are trying to implement.

1. It is better to incorporate bias into weights i.e. `w` will be `3x1` and you have to append a column of ones at the end to your input features. This will allow you implement `wx+b` using matrix multiplication i.e. in vectorized fashion.
2. You are not updating `out`. You should have added the following line:
   `out(j,1) = y > 0;`
3. Why do you put this condition: `if(out(j,1)~=desired_out(j,1))`? It is not mentioned on Wikipedia. Anyway, if you want to update only on mistakes, then you have to update differently on mistakes done on positive and negative samples. See [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/ML10/lect0125.pdf).
4. Doing `input(j,1)*desired_out(j,1)` is wrong. According to Wikipedia, it should be `(desired_out(j,1)-out(j,1))`.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
input = [0 0 1; 0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1] % input vector
num_in = 4; % number of samples
desired_out = [0;1;1;1] % desired output
w=zeros(3,1); % weight vector, initially zero
iterations = 100; % number of iterations to go through

for i = 1:iterations
   out = zeros(4,1);
   for j = 1:num_in % go per row of x
      y = input(j,1)*w(1,1)+input(j,2)*w(2,1)+w(3,1); % sum
      out(j,1) = y>0;
      w(1,1) =w(1,1)+input(j,1)*(desired_out(j,1)-out(j,1));
      w(2,1) = w(2,1)+input(j,2)*(desired_out(j,1)-out(j,1));
      w(3,1) = w(3,1)+input(j,3)*(desired_out(j,1)-out(j,1));
   end
end
out %print the output
```

This could be vectorized further by using matrix multiplications instead of `for` loops, but I will leave that up to you.